# How do I pick which router should be my main router?

Tags: router, routing, wireless-access-point

Right now our home network is using a FiOS-G1100 modem-router device and is acting also as a MoCA bridge for the set top boxes in our house. We just purchased three Velop nodes to set up as access points throughout our house and have disabled all other routers to prevent impacting the performance of the mesh network. What I am not sure of is which device(s) should be responsible for the routing in our house. I can set the G1100 into bridge mode and allow the Velop nodes to handle all of the routing, or I can set the Velop into bridge mode and let the G1100 do all of the routing. How do I decide which would be a better system to handle the routing?

Answer (score 2):

The router that Verizon gives you can handle the connection speed you are paying for.
(In terms of CPU/ram/interface throughput)

If you take it out of the main role:

- You will lose the on-screen guides to your set-top boxes along with the video on-demand services. The VZ router can be put behind another router to enable these services again, but then you are needlessly powering another device.
- You will no longer be able to receive connection troubleshooting through Verizon customer service. (They will ask you to plug directly into the VZ device for troubleshooting, and will basically tell you they can't help you with "advanced routers".)

Without model numbers of the device you want to put in this role, it's hard to say if you will lose a total percentage of the bandwidth you are paying for.

It's probably best to keep it as the main router and bridge the mesh devices to it.